# Theorem 1.36 in Rudin's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces

I have a few questions regarding the proof of Theorem 1.36 in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*:

- Why does $V$ being open imply $x/t\in V$ for some $t<1$.
- How does the inequality $\mu_V(x-y)<r$ come about from $x-y\in rV$ **and** (a)? All I can gather is that $\mu_V(x-y)\leq r$ (note the lesser **or equal**) from the fact that $x-y\in rV$ and the definition of $\mu_V$.
- Why is every non-zero $x$ not in some $V$?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Answer to 1): because $\{t∈\Bbb R^∗∣x/t∈V\}$
  is open and contains $1.$
- Answer to 2): $(x−y)/r∈V$
  implies $μ_V((x−y)/r)<1,$
  i.e. $μ_V(x−y)<r.$
- Answer to 3): by Rudin's definition, all topological vector spaces are Hausdorff.